# Tomcat websockets and separate java process communication

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, websocket, tomcat7

I have a `tomcat 7.0.53` server running for the purpose of communicating between `java` and the website through `websockets`. I wrote the website script as well as the `websocket server java code` and they communicate and work correctly. However the information I want passed to the website is from another `java program` running in the **background** on a Linux machine. The problem lies however with that when I try to pass messages into a `sendmessage` type of function on the `websocket server java code`, it thinks that no `sessions` are open to send the `websocket message` to even if I do have the website opening waiting for a message from the separate java process to be passed through the `websocket server`. I found out this problem arises since I have to make a new instance of the websocket server when passes messages from my separate java process into the `websocket server` `sendmessage` function and thus there are no `websocket` sessions in that instance. I am stumped as to a way around this problem other then to making a `socket` between my `websocket server` and the other java process running which will be messy and want to avoid. Does anyone else know anyway else this can be done with communicating a separate java process with a `websocket server` for tomcat, or is this just impossible to do without making a socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. Could you share the code you are using to provide more context as to what you are attempting server side?

I believe you should be able to create a websocket client endpoint from the second java program. You can find examples of java websocket clients in the web such as the following:

http://www.hascode.com/2014/11/creating-different-websocket-chat-clients-in-java/

hope this helps

Comment: oh wow i guess i never added my answer here, I actually found the answer out a while ago which is mostly like what you said. Thanks though for answering some questions left untouched :)